# Allure report does not show respective build numbers in Allure History trend

Tags: cypress, github-actions, allure

I am using **cypress** and integrated it with **allure**, My automation is getting triggered by **github-actions** and I would to have history trend for it.

The Process which I followed to generate the history trend is:

1. run test execution which will generate folder **allure-results**
2. run command `allure generate --clean` it will generate folder `allure-report`
3. copy **history** folder from folder `allure-report` to folder `allure-results`
4. run command `allure generate --clean` it will generate folder `allure-report`
5. open index.html inside folder `allure-report`
6. go to `TREND` section and see the `history-trend`
7. again run test execution
8. again copy the `history` folder from `allure-report` to `allure-report`
9. run command `allure generate --clean`
10. open `index.html` inside `allure-report`
11. go to `TREND` section and see the `history-trend`

For `history-trend` in **X** axis, I can see build number is `1` for every run, I was expecting it to increased every time based on you last execution build value at right most

[image]

would be helpful to know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be to:

1. Run the tests
2. `allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report`
3. `mkdir -p allure-results/history && cp -r allure-report/history/* allure-results/history/ || true`
4. `allure serve` - to open up the reports.

`allure-results/` directory contains the history(which you want). 
`allure-report/` directory contains just the last run.

You need to execute at least 2 runs for the history to "be working".

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting with Allure, and I had similar problem. Right now, I'm using docker from @frank-escobar - that I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62155628/3497625

The history has increasing build numbers. Maybe look into sources, and find out how it is done.

What I can see there is an `executor.xml` file in the new `allure-reports` dir, that has context like:

```
{ "reportName": "default", "buildName": "default #17", "buildOrder": "17", "name": "Automatic Execution", "reportUrl": "../17/index.html", "buildUrl": "", "type": "another" }
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the initial question. An **answer** is not supposed to be a **I have the similar question** section.